# Find available meeting slots between two times

Tags: php, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to work out how many meeting slots are available between two times. I'm sure I'm missing something simple with the code below as I don't often use while loops.

```
$start = strtotime( 'tomorrow 9am' );
$end = strtotime( 'tomorrow 9:30am' );
$length = 900;
$meetings = array();
$i = 0;

while ( $start < $end ) {
    $meetings[$i]['start'] = $start;
    $meetings[$i]['end'] = $start + $length;
    $start + $length;
    $i++;
}
```

It seems to be causing an infinite loop, but I can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't increment the variable `$start`.

```
$start + $length;
```

This does nothing in itself and probably misses an equal sign. It should probably be:

```
$start += $length;
```

Comment: Of course, knew it would be something that simple, cheers!